# HTML change content using javascript,ajax,jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table in my phtml file.

```
<table width="700" class="detais" cellpadding="10px;">
<tr><td></td><td></td></table>
```

I also have a drop down, on change of this drop down it will call a javascript which is

```
function filterbyaptno(){
     var idno = document.getElementById("aplist").value;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'address',
        type: 'POST',                    
        data:"idno="+idno,
         success:function(result) { 
            var numRecords = parseInt(result.rows.length);
            if(numRecords>0)
            {
              for(var i = 0; i<numRecords;i++)
               {
                 var html ='<div class="support"><table><tr>      <td>'+result.row[i].firstname+'</td>                        
               +'<td>'+result.rows[i].advice+'</td>'         
               +'<td>'+result.rows[i].customdata+'</td><tr></table></div>' 
               }
           $('.detais').replaceWith(html);//am trying to change the table content
             }
         });
   }
```

But what happens if the result has more records it just give me only the last record.
And also if i change the drop down again it never works.
Can anyone help me how to do this? Is there any way in javascript to modify the content of the table based on the response of controller;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loop the results you:

```
var html = ..
```

which replaces whats already in the `html` variable.

Declare `var html` outside the for loop & always append (`html += ...`) within the loop.

You probably also want to setup the container `<div class="support"><table>` outside the loop also, only adding rows within.

Comment: That was a nice help from you brother.I don know why the drop down results does not change if i click on one results and trying to see another result.

Comment: @Indira you replace `$('.detais')` with the stuff in the 1st click, so you need to make sure you add a new element with class `detais` to replace with on the next click, e.g. `<div class="support detais">` if that's not the prob you will need to post a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-assigning the value of the `html` variable in each iteration of the `for` loop which means that in each iteration you're replacing the previous value with the new value, rather than concatenating the previous value and new value.

Modify your code to look like this:

```
if (numRecords > 0) {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
        html += '<div class="support"><table><tr>      <td>' + result.row[i].firstname + '</td>' + ' < td > ' + result.rows[i].advice + ' < /td>' + '<td>' + result.rows[i].customdata + '</td > < tr > < /table></div > '
    }
    $('.detais ').replaceWith(html); //am trying to change the table content
}
```